# swank-js setup fails connection refused etc

Tags: node.js, emacs, slime

On Ubuntu 13.10, Emacs 24.3.50.1, using both quicklisp and package, I've tried to follow the setup instructions here:

https://github.com/swank-js/swank-js

and here:

http://www.idryman.org/blog/2013/03/23/installing-swank-dot-js/

...which I followed closest, using the "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000" in a terminal, as well as this  setup-slime-js.el file (can't list more than two links) But this is the error I get:

Connecting to Swank on port 4005..
open-network-stream: make client process failed: connection refused, :name, SLIME Lisp, :buffer, nil, :host, localhost, :service, 4005, :nowait, nil

Any ideas what I've done wrong should do?

Comment: How exactly did you install `swank-js`? (globally, or locally). Did you run it prior to connecting? (if you installed it globally, to run it means that you executed `$ swank-js`. The error message would suggest that the SWANK server isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 4005?`

If that does not work, I would advice you to link or post the relevant parts of setup-slime-js.el

Comment: Very stupid of me, yes, reran on 4005, but now I get this error: "error in process filter: condition-case: net-read error: (cl-assertion-failed (plusp length))
error in process filter: net-read error: (cl-assertion-failed (plusp length))"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might have been as simple as the fact that I mistakenly assumed that installing npm via Synaptic on Ubuntu would also install node. It didn't. Following the http://www.idryman.org/blog/2013/03/23/installing-swank-dot-js/ tutorial more closely got me to the slime node repl.

. . . but then these are the kinds of problems you get when you allow people like me to buy and operate computers. . . .

Comment: You'll want to install node from a ppa because last I checked the default node package in ubuntu was severely out of date.